# How to implement CRF in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow2.0, crf

I would like to follow this tutorial: https://www.kaggle.com/nikkisharma536/ner-with-bilstm-and-crf

but use Tensorflow 2. It requires that I implement CRF.

How do I do this in Tensorflow 2? I know there is a CRF class in `tensorflow-addons`, but there is no guide on how to use it.